# disable scheduling with properties file

Tags: java, spring, configuration, scheduled-tasks

I would like to disable spring scheduling via an external config file.  I have the config file setup and the task in the example below logs out the following.
`INFO MainTaskScheduler:36 - scheduled task: Update converted bookings false.`  So im most of the way there.

What im looking to achieve is to not to have to put logic inside each task method to determine if scheduling properties has been enabled.

So something like this on my config file (this isn't valid code) 
`@EnableScheduling(${enable.scheduling})`

My working snippets

---

**AppConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan( /*etc*/})
public class AppConfiguration {

}
```

**MainTaskScheduler**

```
@Component
public class MainTaskScheduler {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Value("${enable.scheduling}")
    private Boolean enableScheduling;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=300) // every 5 minutes -- check if any existing quotes have been converted to bookings
    public void updateConvertedBookings() {
        log.info("scheduled task: Update converted bookings "+enableScheduling);
        // logic for class here
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
enable.scheduling=false
```

Comment: Use profiles. Create a separate `@Configuration`  class for the `@EnableScheduling` which is only enabled in a certain profile.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring boot, you can use `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation to enable or disable scheduling:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${enable.scheduling}'=='true'")
```

Comment: I like this answer.  However I dont have it setup as spring boot.. is there a way i can use this without that dependency?

Comment: No thats not possible as this annotation is part of the spring boot.

Comment: didn't work... i'm trying to disable scheduling for tests in spring boot